# Variants of Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

A project of mine is to compare different variants of Hadoop, it is said that there are many of them out there, but googling didn't work well for me :(

Does anyone know any different variants of Hadoop? The only one I found was Haloop.

Comment: Hadoop is a specific implementation of Google's MapReduce system. As far as I know, there's only one Hadoop.

Comment: This might be helpful:
http://www.technology-mania.com/2011/03/understanding-what-is-hadoop.html

Comment: Did you mean flavors of Hadoop?

Answer (score 1):

I think the more generic term is "map reduce":

http://www.google.com/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=map+reduce&safe=active

Comment: The query was about Hadoop and not about MR. Now a days we can get lot of flavors for Hadoop also.

Comment: Yes, but if you know the name of what you're looking for it can help expand your horizons.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you mean by different variants for Hadoop.

But, there are a lot of companies providing commercial support or providing their own versions of Hadoop (open-source and proprietary). You can find more details [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Hadoop#Commercially_supported_Hadoop-related_products).

For ex., [MapR](http://www.mapr.com/) has it's own proprietary implementation of Hadoop, but they claim it's compatible with Apache Hadoop, which is a bit vague because Apache Hadoop is evolving and there are no standards around Hadoop API. Cloudera has it's own version of Hadoop [CDH](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/SUPPORT/Downloads) which is based on the Apache Hadoop. [HortonWorks](http://www.hortonworks.com/) has been spun from Yahoo, which provides commercial support for Hadoop.

You can find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412590/hadoop-distribution-differences). Hadoop is evolving very fast, so this might be a bit stale.

Answer (score 0):

This can refer to
- hadoops file system,
- or its effective support for map reduce...
- or even more generally, to the idea of cloud / distributed storage systems.

Best to clarify what aspects of hadoop you are interested In.

Of course when comparing hadoop academically, you must first start looking at GFS- since that is the origin of hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

Taking aside HBase we can see hadoop as two layers - storage layer and map-reduce layer.
Storage layer has the following really different implementation which would be interesting to compare: standard hadoop file system, HDFS over Cassandra (Brisk), HDFS over S3, MapR hadoop implementation.
MapR also have changed Map-reduce implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This site http://www.nosql-database.org/ has a list of a lot of NoSql DBs out there. Maybe it can help you.